# Simple software for working with webcam

Tags: webcam

Is there some simple software, that can **only take pictures** (or take pictures and shoot video) from webcam?

I'm looking for **single-purpose simple application**, not some complicated streaming/broadcasting solutions.

Is there any **freeware** app that does just that?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: What web cam? Surely when you bought it, it came with software, or is it integrated in your notebook?

Comment: The software which comes with webcam is awful and too overloaded with features, graphics... It's too complicated.

Comment: It came with software, but that doesn't work on my current operating system, Windows 7. Also, Vasiliy Borovyak is right.

Answer (score 2):

Try this site

[Userbooth](http://www.userbooth.com/demo/)

interesting demo they have.. it will capture for you and give you a link where you can download that image.

Requires flash

Answer (score 1):

Webcam Timershot

This PowerToy lets you take pictures at specified time intervals from a Webcam connected to your computer and save them to a location that you designate.

Can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple solution to your problem... try this link http://tucows.com/preview/502646

I hope this will solve your problem. good luck

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)